# Tool for filling in XML file based on XSD

Tags: windows, xml

Can anybody recommend a good tool for filling data into XML documents restricted by an XML Schema Definition (XSD)?

My XSD defines the content of and application form with lots of optionals, choices, regular expressions and enumerations and I would like an automatic user friendly interface for create valid XML documents. Eg. to let testers easily create valid input for a software system.

edit: It is for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it in a while, but I believe Liquid XML Studio can do this. There is a free community edition you can download [here.](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Liquid-Xml-Studio-Version-Comparison.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what operating system you are using.

For testing web services on Windows, you can try [**Storm**](http://www.codeplex.com/storm) and the associated [**WCF Storm**](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/default.aspx). When filling in XML requests Storm does do a bit of hand holding with proper data format and choices.